# Complex Magento Multi-Site & Multi-Currency Solution Required

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a complex online store, meaning that we sell direct to retail customers and we wholesale to stores different countries, and I am very confused as to how you set this up with multi-site and multi-currency.

**The Products**

Wholesalers can order products before retail customers can, so there are products that wholesale shopper groups can ONLY see, on their wholesale site and in their currency, and then some time later that product is *also* available on the retail store too.

**Wholesale Challenge**

The wholesalers need to be charged in their currency and the price needs to be set manually for that currency. It's very important.

So for example, if you are a wholesale customer in Australia, you need to see the AUD price when browsing, and be charged AUD on your invoice. This AUD price **needs** to be set manually by us. *Because of market restrictions*, the AUD wholesale price cannot just be the currency converted from NZ (my base currency).

And this needs to be done for a number of currencies - NZD, AUD, GBP, EUR etc. We also have some user-group pricing too for wholesale customers - so a particular customer who shops in GBP might have a different price to all other GBP wholesale customers. This seems easy enough to just set a new price for different groups.

**Retail Challenge**

For the time being, it's fine for retail customers to be seeing a converted price on the daily conversion rate, and then be paying in the base currency at the checkout, and charged a conversion fee from their bank. But in the future we would want to change to them actually paying in their local currency.

Any ideas on how this can be set up properly, as it is very confusing. We are already running the retail store on Magento and it's going great.

We are using Community Edition 1.7

Comment: I've set up a new store, under the same website, and it has it's own view. But I can't see how to set a product price in the other currency when I'm editing the product, even if I change to the other store in the dropdown at the top left.

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand German?
Have a look at my tutorial.
http://www.magecoder.de/mehrere-wahrungen-currencies-in-magento/